# Align navbar list to right and keep image and selector on left

Tags: html, css, navbar

Im tring here to set the list tags to float right in the navbar and keep my image at the left and the selector with it, and trying to set the search over the list aswell. Already try everything, im just starting with coding and cant find a way to solve

```css
 .fixed-top {
   position: fixed;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 1030;
   top: 0;
   border-width: 0 0 1px;
 }
 #nav ul li a {
   display: block;
   padding: 7px 15px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #FFFFFF;
 }
 #nav li a:hover {
   color: #000000;
   background-color: #fff;
 }
 select option {
   margin: 40px;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   color: #fff;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 }
 select {
   margin-left: 10px;
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-top: 5px;
   background: #696969;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   border: none;
 }
 input[type=text] {
   margin-left: 840px;
 }
 .navbar-superior {
   float: right;
   margin-bottom: -20px;
 }
 .contenedora {
   width: 100%;
   float: right;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   background-color: #696969;
   box-shadow: 10px 0 10px #000000;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
   border-top: 1px solid #000000;
 }
 .navbar-derecha li {
   float: left;
 }
 .contenedora * {
   float: left;
   list-style: none;
 }
```

```html
<div id="nav" class="fixed-top">
  <div class="contenedora">
    <!-- Navegador Superior - logo  -->
    <a href="">
      <img src="images/logo.png">
    </a>
    <select>
      <option val="">Argentina</option>
      <option val="1">Algeria</option>
      <option val="2">..</option>
      <option val="3">...</option>
      <option val="4">....</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar"><a href=""><i class="material-icons">search</i></a>
    </input>
    <div class="navbar-superior">
      <ul class="navbar-derecha">
        <li><a href="#">Soluciones para </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contáctenos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mi Cuenta</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Carrito</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Navbar Derecha -->
  </div>
  <!-- Navegador superior -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the asterisk "*" from `.contenedora * {...}`, And instead add the `list-style:none` to the `.navbar-derecha li {...}` class.

Also remove `margin-bottom: -20px;` form your `.navbar-superior {...}` class such that it looks like

```
.navbar-superior {
   float: right;
}
```

Remove the `margin-left` from the `input[type=text]`, Wrap your `text-input` and your search text in a div tag which you have to float to the **right**

```
   <div style="float:right;">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar"><a href=""><i class="material-icons">search</i></a>
   </div>
```

Make sure your code looks like in the  **example** below.

```css
.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  top: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
#nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav li a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
select option {
  margin: 40px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
select {
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background: #696969;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
}
input[type=text] {} .navbar-superior {
  float: right;
}
.contenedora {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #696969;
  box-shadow: 10px 0 10px #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
.navbar-derecha li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
.contenedora {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav" class="fixed-top">
  <div class="contenedora">
    <!-- Navegador Superior - logo  -->
    <a href="">
      <img src="images/logo.png">
    </a>
    <select>
      <option val="">Argentina</option>
      <option val="1">Algeria</option>
      <option val="2">..</option>
      <option val="3">...</option>
      <option val="4">....</option>
    </select>
    <div style="float:right;">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar"><a href=""><i class="material-icons">search</i></a>
    </div>
    </input>
    <div class="navbar-superior">
      <ul class="navbar-derecha">
        <li><a href="#">Soluciones para </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contáctenos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mi Cuenta</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Carrito</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Navbar Derecha -->
  </div>
  <!-- Navegador superior -->
</div>
```

Hope that helped you.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but when i insert the img, the select goes bottom right to the img and the navb with the input are going to top right, i think its more about css padding and margin right?

Comment: @FrancoPapalardo Yeah, and also using percentages instead of pixels with help you solve the problem.